# How do you adjust loop cuts/edge loops after the fact

Tags: edges

I have some loop cuts.
I have clicked around and done a few more things and now I want to adjust the amount of loop cuts I made a while ago.
How do I go in and edit the count of them?

[image]

Comment: If you've already "set" them, you're pretty much stuck. If you want to adjust the amount, you'll have to do it manually, I'm afraid. Ctrl+R to add new loops, and to remove them, select the whole loop (Alt+Click - hold Shift when selecting multiple loops), then press X and select "dissolve edges".

Comment: Note to self. Use git to track versions of something (ffs). Thanks for the bad news Christopher. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 about git... I have thinked about that in the past, but I will not recommend that, maybe only for little projects. 

A git repository with binaries files can grow so much as git can't only backup the diff's of the files, git will create a whole new copy of the file in his DB.

If you are on Windows you can activate the file history in settings, it will make backups of the modified files in folders you select from from every 10 minutes to... I think once a day. and with that you can roll back easily to any version of the file, even open 2 or more version at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, often when modelling, before making a big, destructive step, I'll just copy (Shift+D) the model, and shoot it like 500 units away on some axis (or occasionally move it to a separate collection). That way, if I'm happy with my changes to the base model, I can just delete them later, or if I screwed something up, I can just copy the "copy" and bring it back to try again.

Comment: gusdleon - Hopefully this inspires/helps - I've now been tracking the changes with git and branching (just the .blend file) and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help all.